# Can we use TransientFaultHandling framework with SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a shared Data Access Layer that will be used for SQL Azure as well as for SQL Server. I explored web and it seems we can use Transient Fault Handling Framework with SQL Azure but I don't see any link that says we can use it for SQL Server.

Can we use [Transient Fault Handling Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680934%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) for SQL Server?